# Alternative for vpython for 3D simulations (molecular dynamics)?

Tags: python-3.x, visualization, simulation

In working on a simple program to simulate and visualize crystal vibrations and molecular dynamics.

I'm not a very experienced programmer so I looked for an easy-to-use tool to work with, and I found that [vpython](http://vpython.org/) (now GlowScript apparently) is simple enough and gives good results. But it lacks some basic functions like panning the scene, which breaks the deal for me.

What other tools are there out there, with reasonable learning curves (not raw opengl), can I use to create 3D simulations? (preferably within the python environment)

[Here](http://www.glowscript.org/#/user/GlowScriptDemos/folder/Examples/program/AtomicSolid-VPython) - An example in vpython similar to what I want to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have look at

http://vispy.org

Python based module.

Also python module specifically for molecular visualization. 
https://pymol.org/2/